# Minimum number of Pairwise sum of elements in a set

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Let A be a non-empty finite sequence of n distinct integers $a_1 \lt a_2 \lt...\lt a_n$. Define $B=\{a_i +a_j | 1\le i,j \le n\}$ For example if $A=\{1,4\} , B =\{2,5,8\}$.How do you show that $$|B| \ge 2n-1$$ where |B| means the number of elements in B?

How should I approach these kind of sums? I think that somehow the least value of |B| will be when A contains an arithmetic progression but how should I prove it? Please help.

Comment: see Melvyn B.Nathanson's [Additive Number Theory](https://www.amazon.com/Additive-Number-Classical-Graduate-Mathematics-dp-1441928480/dp/1441928480/) ( $\S 1.5$ Small sumsets: The case $|2A| \le 3k-4$).

Comment: Look at Nathanson's book more carefully, the stuff you need appear earlier ($\S 1.2$, page 8). In particular, to prove $B \ge 2n-1$, one just need to notice $B$ contains at least following $2n-1$ distinct elements: 
$$\begin{align} & a_1 + a_1 < a_1 + a_2 < a_2 + a_2 < a_2 + a_3\\
& < \cdots  < a_i + a_i < a_i + a_{i+1} < a_{i+1} + a_{i+1} \\
& < \cdots  < a_{n-1} + a_{n-1} < a_{n-1} + a_n < a_n + a_n\end{align} $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea here is to find $2n-1$ explicit elements of $B$ that you know are different.  How can you be sure they're different?  One way is to choose them in such a way that you know each one is smaller than the last.

Imagine your original set consists of $a_1<a_2<...<a_n$.  Once you sort it that way, it's clear what the smallest number of the sumset is: $a_1+a_1$.  How do I make it slightly bigger?  Replace $a_1$ by $a_2$ to get $a_1+a_2$.  And I can make that even bigger by instead doing $a_1+a_3$.  Then $a_1+a_4$, and so on until I reach $a_1+a_n$.  Now I can't increase the second number anymore.  But I can increase the first: $a_1+a_n<a_2+a_n$.  And that's smaller than $a_3+a_n$...  Continuing in this fashion, you'll eventually reach $2n-1$ different numbers.

I like visualizing this argument as taking place on the $n \times n$ grid with rows indexed by the first thing you're adding, and columns by the second.  Each time you step to the right or up, you make the sum bigger.  And moving from $(1,1)$ to $(n,n)$ by the path of your choice you use $2n-1$ points.

Comment: Ok .. but how do we know that in which case does the value of |B| = 2n-1? I mean this didn't seem as a rigorous proof that 2n-1 is the minimum value... Could you clarify?

Comment: Once you've found $2n-1$ distinct elements in $B$, you have a proof that $2n-1$ is the minimum value.  In terms of showing when equality holds, one idea is to consider the grid I mentioned in my answer.  All up/right paths encounter $2n-1$ distinct elements, so if $B=2n-1$ that means all up/right paths must encounter the same $2n-1$ elements in the same order.  In particular, you can draw two paths that are identical except that one goes $a_j+a_j \rightarrow a_j+a_{j+1} \rightarrow a_{j}+a_{j+2} \rightarrow a_{j+1}+a_{j+2} \rightarrow a_{j+2}+a_{j+2}$, while the other...

Comment: ...goes $a_j+a_j \rightarrow a_j+a_{j+1} \rightarrow a_{j+1}+a_{j+1} \rightarrow a_{j+1}+a_{j+2} \rightarrow a_{j+2}+a_{j+2}$.  Since the two paths encounter the same elements of $B$ in the same order, we must have $a_{j}+a_{j+2}=a_{j+1}+a_{j+1}$. But this is true for any $j$, so we have an arithmetic progression.

Comment: Thanks for such a great explanation and visualisation!! Though i am still in the process of actually understanding this properly but you surely gave me a path to follow! Thanks!